# Avoid non-breaking-space characters printing as tildes when using texi2dvi in R

Tags: pdf, sweave, r

I'm using the Sweave toolchain in R to generate tex files from Sweave files as part of an R package.  I use the R command:

```
    $(RSCRIPT) -e "tools::texi2dvi( 'file.tex', pdf = TRUE, clean = FALSE )"
```

(part of my a Makefile in inst/doc) to generate the pdf.  Non-breaking-space character ~ seems to be appearing as a real tilde in the resulting pdf.  How do I avoid this?  (I running pdflatex on the .tex file seems to do the trick, but I gather that is more platform dependent than using the R tools to compile the package.  (More on R/Sweave makefiles in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5448916/258662))

Comment: My best solution is to just compile with the native latex tools rather than the R-included tools in the makefile. See this example: https://gist.github.com/1591001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run into the same issue.  At work right now I have a windows machine and the call to tools::texi2dvi seems work just fine, no unbreakable space in the resulting pdf.  However, on my Ubuntu 11.10 machine at home I see the ~ character just as you described if I compile via `tools::texi2dvi`.  My solution has been to use a `system` call from R to get the `pdflatex` if on Linux and `tools::texi2dvi` if on windows.  I have the function as part of a build.R file for whatever project I'm working on that day.

```
compile <- function(){
  if (.Platform$OS != 'windows'){
    system("pdflatex ./tex/MAIN.tex")
  } else {
    tools::texi2dvi(file  = "./tex/MAIN.tex",
                    pdf   = TRUE,
                    clean = FALSE,
                    quiet = FALSE)
  }
}

compile()
```

Comment: thanks for confirming the bug.  Yes, I've been using system calls (or just a custom Makefile) to get around this too, but it seems unsatisfying that tools::tex2dvi has such a bug on Ubuntu.  I guess it's worth posting this to r-devel then?